# reading a specific number that falls between two strings from a text file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, string, text, fs

I am a Node.JS learner from SAP background and for the past few weeks and am trying to capture a number that falls between two strings in a text file. I have tried to collate by reading many sample codes, but not succeeded. How could I write this code correctly? I tried with the below code. However, it is only partial code and does not function the way I would like it to.

Requirements: TextFile has the data as shown below, file to be read to capture the number that falls between "FETCH:" and "RECORDS" and write that number into another text file.

|27.07.2020|10:19:09|1 LUWs confirmed and 1 LUWs to be deleted with function module
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|OPEN_CURSOR JOIN_FLEXA_BKPF
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH:1000 RECORDS
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|OPEN_CURSOR JOIN_FLEXA_BKPF
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH: 193 RECORDS
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|OPEN_CURSOR JOIN_FLEXA_BKPF
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH:500 RECORDS
|27.07.2020|10:19:10|OPEN_CURSOR JOIN_FLEXA_BKPF

I wrote this code by myself. I am able to read line by line, but not able to capture the number.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input  : fs.createReadStream('BIREQFILE.txt'),
    output : process.stdout,
    console : false
});
readInterface.on('line',function(line){
    const extractNumbersFromString = line.match(/-?\d+/g);
    fs.writeFile('output.txt',extractNumbersFromString);
    
});
```

Thanks & Regards

```
LN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex need to change to line.match(/(?<=(FETCH:))\d+/g)

```js
const line = "27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH:1000 RECORDS"
const extractNumbersFromString = line.match(/(?<=(FETCH:))\d+/g)
console.log(extractNumbersFromString) // outputs ["1000"]
```

Comment: But the requirement is that to read line by line in the file and provide the output written into file  with values  1000 ,193  and 500

Comment: Also , the Date and time as shown in each line is not same always, so cannot hardcode string with date and time.

Comment: I just provided a standalone working example. In your code you need to change regex at below place

readInterface.on('line',function(line){
    const extractNumbersFromString = line.match(/(?<=(FETCH:))\d+/g);

Comment: Kapil , on mentioned the suggested code , the output is  printing 1000 in every line on the console , but not 1000 , 193 and 150.                                                                                               when it is reading every line of the file , it should have captured the value from each line , but instead capturing only the first value and printing the same value in each line of console.

Comment: readInterface.on('line',function(line){
    line = "27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH:1000 RECORDS"
    const extractNumbersFromString = line.match(/(?<=(FETCH:))\d+/g)
    fs.writeFileSync('output.txt',extractNumbersFromString);
    console.log(extractNumbersFromString);

Comment: remove line = "27.07.2020|10:19:10|FETCH:1000 RECORDS" statement from your code. It was just for example. In your code, line value will be set dynamically for each line.